# How to change the background color of one specific element row instead of all rows?

Tags: html, css

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUCp8.png)

```
<div data-recordid="recRQEgAz0YtDfDxz" class="js-list-item d-flex justify-content-center flex-column box position-relative    sw-background-color-151c48 sw-margin-bottom-4xs sw-border-style-solid sw-border-width-m sw-border-color-ee034f sw-border-radius-l sw-box-shadow-m hover:sw-box-shadow-m sw-padding-top-xs sw-padding-bottom-xs sw-padding-left-xs sw-padding-right-xs sw-cursor-default" data-editor-status="attached">       <div class="d-flex sw-js-list-item-header">      <div class="w-sm-100 text-center">    <div data-type="staticImage" data-
```

Im trying to change the background colour via CSS if this specific elemnt data-recordid="recRQEgAz0YtDfDxz"

Ive only can change the backgound colour of all listings.
Very thankful if someone helps me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors ?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: The solution will depend on the exact scenario you're trying to solve. If the recordid is static and never expected to change, then the existing solution below will work. If you need to dynamically change which row is selected, then you'll need to either use JavaScript or compute this server-side somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements by their attributes.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors.

```css
div[data-recordid="recRQEgAz0YtDfDxz"] {
    background-color: ...;
}
```

Comment: Scriptim you are the Best.  Thank you so so much    . I have to learn a lot by the way.